# Search File A with Terms from File B and save output to individual TXT files based off search term from File B

Tags: awk, sed, grep, output

FILE-A has 100,000 lines.  FILE-B is 50 search terms.  I'm looking to complete the search of FILE-A (CSV or TXT) with the various terms from FILE-B (CSV or TXT) AND -- here is the kicker --  save the results in individual TXT files based off the search terms from FILE-B.

Example:

FILE-A

```
123
45678
1239870
2349878
39742366876
41967849
789
910
2378
6723
```

FILE-B

```
1
2
23
78
```

Results = "1.txt" with all matching lines from FILE-A, "2.txt" with all lines matching from FILE-A, "23.txt", "78.txt" and so on.  So if FILE-B has 50 search terms, I would end up with 50 TXT files, named with the search term, assuming at least one hit with said term from FILE-A.

I have searched using "fgrep -f FILE-B.txt FILE-A.csv >> output.txt"  This puts all of the search terms from FILE-B found in FILE-A into one "output.txt". I'm instead looking to separate them into individual text files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Grep + Xargs

```bsh
xargs -d '\n' sh -c '
    for term; do grep "$term" fileA > "$term.txt"; done
' xargs-sh < fileB
```

<sup>Improved by [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas).</sup>

##### Grep + Shell

Generally [using shell loops to read a file is bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), but here `fileB` is much smaller than `fileA` so it won't significantly hurt performance.

```
while IFS= read -r term; do
    grep "$term" fileA > "$term.txt"
done < fileB
```

##### Awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pat[$0];next}{for(term in pat){if($0~term){print>term}}}' fileB fileA
```

- [`NR==FNR{pat[$0];next}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-imply) reads the first file given as an argument and puts each line in the array `pat`.
- `{for(term in pat){if($0~term){print>term}}}` is self-explainable: For each `term` in the array, test if the current line  matches the term and print it to a file named accordingly if yes.

Not all Awks will allow for many files to be open at the same time. One way to tackle this, as suggested by [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton), is to use a `close` statement and to use the append operator:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pat[$0];next}{for(term in pat){if($0~term){print>>term;close(term)}}}' fileB fileA
```

Comment: For the awk script, instead of closing and opening an output file for each write (there is significant overhead in doing that), I'd use another variable, say `prev_term`, and do something like `if (term != prev_term) {close(prev_term); prev_term=term}`.   This will only close the output file when term changes, not every time output is written.

Answer (score 2):

This should be efficient as it uses a first pass with `grep -F` (which is very fast) to output just the lines from FILE-A that match lines from FILE-B (which presumably will be a much smaller number of lines than the original 100,000 in FILE-A) so then the awk script doesn't have so many lines from FILE-A to compare and can loop through those when reading FILE-B instead of looping through the FILE-B lines when reading FILE-A and so is able to only open/close 1 output file for each line of FILE-B rather than open/close 1 output file at a time for every line of FILE-B * every line that matches it in FILE-A to avoid the potential "too many open files" error.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

grep -F -f 'FILE-B' 'FILE-A' |
awk '
    NR==FNR{ lines[++numLines]=$0; next }
    {
        close(out)
        out = $0 ".txt"
        for (i=1; i<=numLines; i++) {
            line = lines[i]
            if (index(line,$0)) {
                print line > out
            }
        }
    }
' - 'FILE-B'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ head -100 *.txt
==> 1.txt <==
123
1239870
41967849
910

==> 2.txt <==
123
1239870
2349878
39742366876
2378
6723

==> 23.txt <==
123
1239870
2349878
39742366876
2378
6723

==> 78.txt <==
45678
2349878
41967849
789
2378
```